# UIScrollView containing CGRect line graph not scrolling (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, drawrect

I'm trying to make a line graph drawn using a CGRect scrollable by the user. I've set its container view to be scrollable (i want a horizontal scroll so the line can extend past the screen), but it doesn't appear to be having any effect. Here's the code in my actual view controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var graphView: GraphView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
logWeightButton.enabled = false
logWeightField.delegate = self
logWeightField.keyboardType = .NumberPad
self.view.addSubview(containerView)
containerView.addSubview(graphView)
containerView.contentSize = graphView.rectDisplay.size
pageLoad()
  }
```

and here's the code declaring the CGRect(within a UIView class)

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    if dataPoints.count == 0 {
        return
    } else {
        self.drawLine(dataPoints, rect: rect, xCoordinates: nil, color: UIColor.blackColor())
        if xCoordinates.count != 0 {
            self.drawLine(actualPoints, rect: rect, xCoordinates: xCoordinates, color: UIColor.redColor())
        }
        rectDisplay = rect
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that I needed to turn off auto-layout in the storyboard file inspector - if it's not disabled, it can overwrite scroll views.

I also made sure to enable scroll with

```
containerView.scrollEnabled = true
```

and set the containerView frame to

```
self.view.frame
```

I don't have enough reputation to post an image, so here it is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOBJp.png

The graph now scrolls, but my whole display is a mess (I believe because of setting the container frame to the size of the view), so the cycle continues.

FINAL UPDATE:

Learned that the frame of the scroll view has to be smaller than its content for it to scroll (which is why setting it to the view frame worked - the width of the view was less than the width of the line graph), so I set my frame to

```
    containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 43.0, y: 147.0, width: 300.0, height: 117.0)
```

And everything works now. Hope this is helpful for someone else!